# Calling C++ function in Matlab, deal with 2-dimensional array, pointer of pointer?

Tags: c++, matlab, pointers, matrix, mex

I am trying to call a function in C++ in Matlab, I thought I have written my functions properly. The function I want to call, looks like this, it has 8 arguments as input.

```
void LimitedPrice(double &dMarketPosition, double** dmatLimitPrice, 
                  char* FileID, double* dvecOpen, double* dvecClose, 
                  double** dmatTempData, int tick, double dMaxBarBack)
 {Bla, Bla, Bla}
```

I want to get 2 values after running this function. Which stored in dMarketPosition, and dmatLimitPrice since they are pointers.

In this function, I have to use some ** (double pointers) to represent my Matrix.

After running this function, **dMarketPosition, dmatLimitPrice** will store what I want, since they are pointers. I have tested my function and I believed my function are written properly.

Now I am ready to write my **mexFunction()**.
My mex function somehow looks like this

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
             int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    if(nrhs!=8){
          mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("LimitPrice: ","I want to 8 inputs");
    }
    // I want two output
    if(nlhs!=2) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("LimitPrice: ","I want to 2 outputs");
    }

   //The first input is a scalar
   double dmarketposition;
   dmarketposition = mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);

   //The second input is a 2-dimensional Matrix
   double **dmatlimitprice;
   *dmatlimitprice = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);

   /*****Assuming I have checked other inputs here properly*****/
   // I want to define my outputs
   // Create 1*1 matrix as output, which is the double value I want 
   plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);
   //The second output is a two dimensional matrix
   plhs[1] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(2,(mwSize)4,mxREAL);
   dmarketposition = mxGetScalar(plhs[0]);
   *dmatlimitprice = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
   // Call the function
   LimitedPrice(dmarketposition, dmatlimitprice, fileid,
   dvecopen, dvecclose, dmattempdata, tick, dmaxbarback);
}
```

The above function does not seem to work... It seems that in mexFunction(),
We would better only pass one-dimensional array, which is double *a like thing.

My key issue is **"How can we deal with 2-dimensional array, which is a matrix"** in mexFunction().

Comment: You dereferenced an uninitialized pointer, of course that does not work.  What you need to do is allocate an array of pointers (use `std::vector<double*>`), and fill it with the addresses of each column in the matrix.  Then you will have a double pointer to pass to your C++ function.

Answer (score 2):

In memory, Matlab stores all `mxArray`s as one chunk of contiguous memory column by column. In that respect, there is no difference beteween a 1D vector and N-D array, they are all stored as a single chunk of memory.
Consider, for example, the following chunk in memory: `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }`
It can be treated as a 1-by-8, 8-by-1, 2-by-4, 4-by-2 or even 2-by-2-by-2 array. Changing the `shape` ([`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)-ing) of the array does not require any change to the actual memory where the data is stored, only to the "header" of the `mxArray`.

What you can do is allocate a 2D matrix internally, call `LimitedPrice` and then copy the result into the output `mxArray` converting it from the internal `double**` representation to `double*` `mxArray` representation.

---

A side note, in your example code you assign `dmarketposition` and `dmatlimitprice` twice: once from the first and second inputs and once from the newly allocated outputs - the second assignment simply overrides the first and it seems like your function `LimitedPrice` will not get the information stored in the `mexFunction` inputs.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that makes an array 2D (or any size other than 1D) is the shape of the array as stored in the `mxArray` structure.  All the data is contiguous.  The stride, or step in bytes between columns, of a 2D array in MATLAB (and `mxArray`s) is always `number_of_rows * element_size`.  For a column-major storage system, that's a way of saying that a contiguous data buffer is used to store all arrays.

Take the basic functions for reading from a `mxArray`:

```
double* mxGetPr(const mxArray*);    // get pointer to start of double buffer
void*   mxGetData(const mxArray*);  // get pointer to start of any data-type buffer
size_t  mxGetM(const mxArray*);     // get number of rows
size_t  mxGetN(const mxArray*);     // get number of columns
```

There is no function like [OpenCV's `T* ptr<T>(int i)`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-ptr) to get a pointer to specified row (or column in MATLAB's case).  To get an element, you just have to access location `irow + icol*numRows`.  This is why it is common to have a `sub2ind`-like function in C/C++:

```
inline mwSize sub2ind(mwSize irow, mwSize icol, mwSize numRows) {
    return irow + icol*numRows; }
```

---

**That was generic advice**, nothing specific to your code.  I'm hesitant to to make specific suggestions since semantics of `LimitedPrice()` is not clear.  The syntax is clear -- it needs a pointer to a pointer -- but often a `**` is used to return a new pointer (internally allocated result) rather than to manage a 2D array.   If it's 2D data then usually there will be two integral types with it to specify dimensions, but I don't see that.

For the reasons above it's hard to provide more specific help, but here here is a big issue to address:

```
double **dmatlimitprice;
*dmatlimitprice = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);  // dereferencing uninitialized pointer, ERROR
```

You *could* make a `double**` that acts as an index into the columns of the input matrix (if that is what you actually need!).  For example:

```
size_t numCols = mxGetN(prhs[1]);
double *dlimitBuffer = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
// Simulate a 2D array:
std::vector<double*> dlimitvec(numCols);
double **dmatlimitprice = &dlimitvec[0]; // or = new double*[numCols]; if you delete[]
for (size_t i=0; i < numCols; ++i)
    datalimitprice[i] = dlimitBuffer + i*numRows;
```

That's assuming you need a `double**` where each `double*` points to the individual columns of some matrix, which is likely not correct, so treat this **as an example**.  You may need to transpose the matrix too.

Also, you make the invalid assignment to  `*dmatlimitprice` twice so it's hard to tell whether you want this as the input or output array.